# Manually pan audio in three.js

Tags: audio, three.js, panning

I'm looking at the [Audio](https://threejs.org/docs/api/en/audio/Audio.html) and [PositionalAudio](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/audio/PositionalAudio) objects, and I cannot find a way to manually pan the audio left or right. Assigning a sound to the PositionalAudio object gives me a panner object inside, but I cannot find any custom adjustments I can make to change the panning.

[image]

I am able to manually set the volume based on distance in my animation loop with setVolume on the sound I want to adjust, but I cannot find anything for panning.

Note, you can see I tried changing the position.x property, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about `PositionalAudio` is that it automatically pans left/right based on its position to the [`AudioListener`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/audio/AudioListener). The `AudioListener` is usually attached to the camera so the viewer gets the effect of 3D positional audio:

- If the audio source is to the left of the listener, it'll come out of the left speakers.
- Center: both speakers
- Right: right speaker

You can see this automatic panning in action [in this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webaudio_sandbox). (I'm not sure why this demo drowns you with 4 audio sources simultaneously. I recommend you mute all audio sources except for the second sphere, then move around it to see how the panning occurs automatically)

Allowing a pan control would defeat the purpose of 3D positional audio. If you want to override the panning, I guess you could apply a filter with `AudioListener.setFilter()` and pass in a [`StereoPannerNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StereoPannerNode), but like I said, that would defeat the purpose of 3D audio.

Comment: Unfortunately, their 3D panning is not sophisticated enough for my needs. I'll see if the StereoPannerNode could work. I did not know setFilter() could do that. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Make sure you use [AudioListener.context](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/audio/AudioListener.context) to get audio context you're already using, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: StereoPannerNode is not supported by Safari, sadly. I am probably going to continue with this audio end of stuff with p5.js, since it has support for almost all browsers and has other neat features such as convolution reverb.

Comment: Yeah, Safari has dismal WebAudio support. It's really frustrating. Are you sure the p5.js features will work in Safari?

Comment: The examples work in Safari, but I can't get them to work with the library itself. It says "web audio is not supported by this browser". I'm confused since the examples appear to work themselves.